# Node.js "unexpected token error" (needs help_

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, unexpected-token

Alright, so I was coding my discord bot (not going to put full code) and I got an unexpected token error. This had happened to me before, but I've tried to check for 2 hours straight and nothing really happened. Here's my code down below.

[Node.js Unexpected Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGi64.gif)

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5ENM.gif)
[error picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFkru.gif)
Idk what to do really so it would really help if someone comments and tries to help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: the error is really helpful, I would start by looking there. what line does it show?

Comment: idk really i've tried to look at it but still confused. if your asking for what the gray line shows, it shows nothing

Comment: can you share the error?

Comment: it is a "parsing error" and its an unexpected token.

Comment: you need to show the error

Comment: alright ill edit the post and show it

Comment: ok i have added it

Comment: seems like you're missing a "})" from client.on, line 22

Comment: im pretty sure error two is what your trying to find

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing parenthesis `)` that belongs to your `client.on('message', ...` argument list and its associated function curly brace. These belong right after your last `if...else` closing curly brace `}` based on a cursory review of your code.

```js
// line 46 follows
}
}) // this is the missing brace and paren
client.login(...)
```

Comment: yep, Smoothie also needs a "}", so missing "})"

Comment: Yeah, caught that right as I posted it; amended. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for helping out, after adding variables the code ended up working :)